Unable to Retrieve loginInfo After Google Authentication in ASP.NET Web Forms
I am implementing Google authentication in my ASP.NET Web Forms application using OWIN. However, after logging in with Google, I am unable to retrieve the loginInfo object in the ExternalLoginCallback method. The loginInfo is always null, which prevents me from accessing the user's information.
Code Implementation:
Configuration Method
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}



public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/login.aspx"),
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "ClientId", // Replace with your actual ClientId
        ClientSecret = "ClientSecret", // Replace with your actual ClientSecret
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google"),
        Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnAuthenticated = context =>
            {
                var emailClaim = context.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
                if (emailClaim != null)
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Email", emailClaim.Value));
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    };
    
    googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
    googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
    googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("openid");

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);
}


ExternalLogin Method

public void ExternalLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/login.aspx/ExternalLoginCallback" };
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, "Google");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}


 ExternalLoginCallback Method

public async Task ExternalLoginCallback()
{
    try
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var loginInfo = await authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            lbl_warning.Text = "User not found.";
            lbl_warning.Visible = true; // Ensure the warning label is visible
            return;
        }

        var emailClaim = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
        // Additional logic to handle the user's email claim can be added here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_warning.Text = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message;
        lbl_warning.Visible = true; // Show the error message
    }
}


Redirect URI
The redirect URI I am using in the Google API Console is:

http://localhost:50180/signin-google

